# Streaming large files with play framework and third party API

Tags: java, playframework, streaming

I'm writing a play 2 application and I am struggling with a file streaming problem.
I retrieve my files using a third party API with a method having the following signature:

```
FileMetadata getFile(OutputStream destination, String fileId)
```

In a traditional Servlet application, if I wanted to send the content to my client I would have done something like:

```
HttpServletResponse resp;
myService.getFile(resp.getOutpuStream, fileId);
```

My problem is that in my play 2 Controller class I don't have access to the underlying OuputStream, so the simplest implementation of my controller method would be:

```
public static downloadFile(String id) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new BAOS(...);
    myApi.getFile(baos,id); //Load inside temp Array      
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new BAIS(baos.toByteArray())
    return Ok(bais);
 }
```

It will work but it requires to load the whole content into memory before serving it so it's not an option (files can be huge).

I was thinking of a solution consisting in:

- Defining a ByteArrayOutputStream (baos) inside my controller
- Calling the third party API with this baos in parameter
- Using the chunk return of the play framework to send the content of
  the baos as soon as something is written inside by the 3rd party API

Problem is that I don't know if it possible (call to getFile is blocking so it would require multiple threads with a shared OutputStream) nor if it's overkill.

As someone ever faced this kind of problem and found a solution?
Could my proposed solution solve my problem?

Any insights will be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**
Based on kheraud suggestion I have managed to have a working, but still not perfect, solution (code below).

Unfortunately if a problem occurs during the call to the getFile method, error is not sent back to the client (because I returned Ok) and the browser waits indefinitely for a file that will never come.

Is there a way to handle this case ?

```
public static Result downloadFile(String fileId {    
      Thread readerThread = null;
      try {
          PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream();
          PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream(pos); 
          //Reading must be done in another thread
          readerThread = new DownloadFileWorker(fileId,pos);
          readerThread.start();

          return ok(pis);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          return internalServerError(ex.toString());

      }
  }

static class DownloadFileWorker extends Thread{
      String fileId;  
      PipedOutputStream pos;

      public DownloadFileWorker(String fileId, PipedOutputStream pos) {
        super();
        this.fileId = fileId
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public void run(){
          try {
              myApi.getFile(pos,fileId);
              pos.close();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I found a way to avoid infinite loading of the page by simply adding a pos.close in the catch() part of the worker thread. Client ends up with a zero KB file but I guess that's better than an infinite waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something in the **Play2 Scala** framework made for that : `Enumerators`. This is very close to what you are thinking about.

You should have a look at this [doc page for details](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaStream)

I didn't find something similar in the Play2 Java API, but looking in the fw code source, you have a :

```
public static Results.Status ok(java.io.InputStream content, int chunkSize)
```

method which seams to be what you are looking for. The implementation can be found in `play.mvc.Results` and `play.core.j.JavaResults` classes.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it. I don't know Scala and only use the Java part of the API for now but if it can help my resolve my problem I will give it a try.

Comment: Ouch, I answered too quickly, I didn't noticed you used play2 with Java. I didn't find the same concept in the Play2 Java API...

Comment: It seems it indeed doesn't exist but it should be possible to mix scala with java [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311380/one-play-2-framework-app-use-both-java-and-scala)

Comment: @Davz I edited my answer, it seams that a Controller methods permits to stream from an InputStream

Comment: My 3rd party API sends the content of the file I request inside the OutputStream I put in parameter. And I want everything that is written on this stream to be sent as the result of the call to the Controller. I have no InputStream available so can't use the method that streams from an InputStream.

Comment: You can have a look at pipes (PipeInputStream, PipeOutputStream), made for that.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about those pipes objects. I will take a look at them to see how I could use them (my concern is that the call to the getFile is blocking, but maybe I could use Promises). Thanks

Comment: @kheraus I accept your answer as you put me on the way with the pipes. I have edited my question to put the working code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the Play! mailing list, there recently was a discussion on the same topic:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/YunJzgxPKsU/discussion

It includes a small snippet that allows non-scala-literates (like myself) use the scala streaming interface of Play!.

Comment: Yes I have double-posted ;-) Code in the mailing list is the same as the one on this page.